# System lock or infinite loop is able to cause reboot?

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux

My question is related to knowledge on embedded Linux.

I just observed a strange reboot on my embedded project, which is very easy to reproduce.

When some condition is triggered, the system will like "freezing". I mean, its like encounter some infinite loop or be locked. Last for several seconds, system will *quietly* reboot. Not even core dump!!

I have no much clue about the cause. Generally will a lock or infinite loop can truly trigger Linux reboot? Or are there any things can freeze system and cause reboot with no core dump happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is common on embedded systems to have a [hardware watchdog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer); a timer implemented in hardware that resets the processor if it is allowed to expire.

Typically some [software monitoring task](http://www.sat.dundee.ac.uk/psc/watchdog/watchdog-background.html) continuously verifies the integrity of the system and restarts the hardware watchdog timer.  If the monitoring task fails to run and the watchdog timer expires, the watchdog triggers a processor reset directly.

Comment: Most probably the real reason +1

Comment: Reasonable enough. I will check what kind of action can let watch dog reboot my system..Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit hard to understand but yes, a "infinite loop" (the proper term is) in any application on any platform (including Linux) can crash a system. This happens obviously because an infinite loop can constantly take up memory and resources until there is none left. You mentioned you are doing embedded development (which can mean many different things) but usually means you are developing low-level applications built into Linux itself; these are more prone to crashing an OS than your average programming venture.

Comment: Thanks!! I will modify..sorry English is not my first language. How about deadlock？ Can it also cause system reboot?